# Is there any fix for Xampp Object not found?

Tags: php, linux, apache, xampp, lampp

Today I tried to open xampp and run apache and MYSQL and they were working but any .php file I try to run It says the following:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
> Error 404
> localhost
> Apache/2.4.53 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/8.1.4 mod_perl/2.0.12 Perl/v5.34.1

I tried to check my files and check my database and they were fine.I Also tried to run it on a Windows Machine and it didn't work.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yea, give it an object to find

Comment: Either your Apache isn't properly configured for object-oriented access, or you simply don't have your files in the right place (e.g. document root).

Comment: My file is like this /opt/lampp/htdocs/Test/Signup.php

Comment: For /opt/lampp/htdocs/Test/Signup.php, are you accessing the php file thru `http://localhost/Test/Signup.php` ? (or you are using other url ?)

Comment: Or did you create a VirtualHost to point to the right directory

Comment: No I didn't create anything.

Comment: And I have accessed  the file like Ken Lee Has said.

Comment: Do you have document root in your httpd.conf set to: `DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"`? If not, then that's your problem. And do you see the default "It works!" HTML document in that folder? If not, then "it works" somewhere, but not at where you're trying to reach things. Check your paths.

Comment: I have just checked my paths and nothing in them is wrong.

Comment: Oh I found it I just uninstalled xampp and deleted the remaining folders then installed it again and created the Database and the tables.And now it is working.Thanks for replies.

Comment: Would you mind posting the answer formally? It'll make it easier for the next person to use your question, since comments are temporary! It's 100% okay to answer your own question and mark it as the solution, even if someone in the comments gave it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I found it I just uninstalled xampp and deleted the remaining folders then installed it again and created the Database and the tables.And now it is working.Thanks for replies.